# Ruby element match

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the index of the first and second instance of a string variable. I want to be able to use any predefined string variable but when I try to do that it gives me an error. I want to be able to declare multiple string variables like ss, aa, ff, etc and use them in place of xx. Can someone help me out?

```
    #aa is a predefined array 
    xx = "--help--"
    find_xx_instance = aa.each_with_index.select{|i,idx| i =~ /xx/} 
    #/--help--/works but not /xx/

    find_xx_instance.map! {|i| i[1]}

    #gives me info between the first two instances of string
    puts aa[find_xx_instance[0]+1..find_xx_instance[1]-1]
```

Comment: I think there is a lot of ambiguity in this question.  The source code seems to be in several ways unrelated to the text paragraph and question. Please test each line of code and see which is the first that behaves in an unexpected way.  Give us a small sample array for `aa`. Please explain precisely what each line after the first assignment is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you just need to pass variable to regular expression. Try this:

```
find_xx_instance = aa.each_with_index.select{|i,idx| i =~ /#{xx}/}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you are given an array of strings, `arr`, a string `str`, and an integer `n`, and wish to return an array `a` of `n` elements `i`, where `i` is the index of the ith+1 instance of `str` in `arr`.

For example:

```
arr = %w| Now is the time for the Zorgs to attack the Borgs |
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "the", "Zorgs", "to", "attack", "the", "Borgs"] 
str = "the"
nbr = 2
```

This is one way:

```
b = arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==str }
  #=> [2, 5, 9] 
b.first(nbr) 
  #=> [2, 5]
```

which can be written

```
arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i]==str }.first(nbr)
```

This For small problems like this one, that's fine, but if `arr` is large, it would be better to terminate the calculations after `nbr` instances of `str` have been found. We can do that by creating a [Lazy enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html):

```
arr.each_index.lazy.select { |i| arr[i]==str }.first(nbr)  
  #=> [2, 5]
```

Here's a second example that clearly illustrates that `lazy` is stopping the calculations after `nbr` strings `str` in `arr` have been found:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.select { |i| arr[i] == str }.first(nbr)
  #=> [2, 5]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I didn't realize I had posted a duplicate answer. Thanks for deleting it and letting me know.